# Using the 'not' operator in Boolean statements for Matlab

Tags: matlab

If a statement like `~(5>4) || (1>10)` is given what does it evaluate to in MATLAB?

What I think is the answer is :

> ~1 || 0 = 0 || 0
>
> = 0

so it evaluates to false.

Am I correct in that the not operator only attaches to the (5 > 4)?

Comment: Who are the downvoters here. If downvoting, at least leave a comment. It is definitely not trivial that expressions are evaluated left to right. Took me a few years before I realized that.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, Matlab would evaluate the logical operators from left to right. See [Operator Precedence](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html) for instances when this would not be the case.

That would mean that `~(5>4) | (1>10)` would first evaluate the left half of the OR:

```
~(5>4) --> ~(1) --> 0
```

Then continuing...

```
0 | (1>10) --> 0 | 0 --> 0
```

Comment: Gotcha. bolean order of operations always confuse me. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Also be aware of `|` vs `||`.  The `|` operator does not short circuit the evaluation, so even if the first `~(5>4)` were somehow true, using `|` would tell Matlab to still evaluate the remaining expressions. Using `||` would cause the evaluation to short circuit on the first true value (for OR comparisons).  Just thought I'd point that out since the original question used `||` vs your answer with `|`. :)